# Robocopy only copy files with double underscore __ - how to

Tags: robocopy

Hi I have a directory I would like to do an automated marge/cpoy on 
but I only what to copy files with double under score xxx__xx.jpg.
Is it possible to setup such a filter with robocopy ?

This is what a have not (copies everything) 
(robocopy 'src' 'dest' /MIR /XJD /R:5 /W:15) ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 4 exit /B 0

please let me know if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

According to [the documentation](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) (robocopy /?) there are four parameters.  The third is what you need for the File(s) to copy (names/wildcards) to be *__*.jpg.

Thus your command line will be:

`robocopy C:\Source C:\Destination *__*.jpg`